# How to unbold title of appendix in list of appendices?

Tags: appendices

I want to unbold the appendix name in list of appendices. How to do that?

[image]

This is my code :

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{times}
 \usepackage{tocbasic}
\newcommand\listappendixname{List of Appendices}
\newcommand\appcaption[1]{%
   \addcontentsline{app}{chapter}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofappendices{%
    \chapter*{\listappendixname}\@starttoc{app}
}
\makeatother

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,
beforeskip=0pt,
entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,
dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}

\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    indent=\ifundefinedorrelax{scr@dte@chapter@lastmaxnumwidth}
    {1.5em}
    {\scr@dte@chapter@lastmaxnumwidth}%
    ]{tocline}{section}
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry{tocline}{subsection}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofappendices
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List Of Appendices}

\chapter{Chapter one}
\chapter{Chapter two}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix one}\appcaption{Appendix one}
...(contents of appendix one)...

\chapter{Appendix two}\appcaption{Appendix two}
...(contents of appendix two)...

\end{document}
```

@Raaja, this is your result for your code, the page number is bold :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For only the appendices list, adding \textnormal in your code unbolds the appendix names in your list:

```
\newcommand\appcaption[1]{%
\addcontentsline{app}{chapter}{\textnormal{#1}}} % added textnormal.
```

For the dots, you can remove \textbf as follows, though it will unbold the dots over your entire contents:

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill, % removed \textbf
```

The result follows:

[image]

**Updated answer**

This replaces the above partial solution completely. The updated answer uses `\DeclareNewTOC` to format the appendix list. Here is the result showing plain formatted text:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\newcommand\listappendixname{List of Appendices}
\newcommand\appcaption[1]{%
   \addcontentsline{app}{appendixlist}{#1}}  <-----% uses new toc style 
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofappendices{%
    \chapter*{\listappendixname}\@starttoc{app}
}
\makeatother

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,
beforeskip=0pt,
entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,
dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}

\DeclareNewTOC[   %<----- new style definition for appendix list.
  tocindent=0em,
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentrylinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,
]{appendixlist}

\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    indent=\ifundefinedorrelax{scr@dte@chapter@lastmaxnumwidth}
    {1.5em}
    {\scr@dte@chapter@lastmaxnumwidth}%
    ]{tocline}{section}
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry{tocline}{subsection}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofappendices
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List Of Appendices}

\chapter{Chapter one}
\chapter{Chapter two}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix one}\appcaption{Appendix one}
...(contents of appendix one)...

\chapter{Appendix two}\appcaption{Appendix two}
...(contents of appendix two)...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer is almost correct, but the page number is bold. I want  page numbers not bold.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include new code that replaces my original attempt. The new solution uses \DeclareNewTOC to create a toc style for the appendix list, where you can control the formatting of the entry. Your original solution used the chapter style for the appendix list and so was inheriting its formatting. My solution gives the appendix list its own formatting style.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, @Dunk the Lunk. Your updated answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{times}
 \usepackage{tocbasic}
\newcommand\listappendixname{List of Appendices}
\newcommand\appcaption[1]{%
   \addcontentsline{app}{chapter}{\textnormal{#1}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofappendices{%
    \chapter*{\listappendixname}\@starttoc{app}
}
\makeatother

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,
beforeskip=0pt,
entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,
dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}

\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    indent=\ifundefinedorrelax{scr@dte@chapter@lastmaxnumwidth}
    {1.5em}
    {\scr@dte@chapter@lastmaxnumwidth}%
    ]{tocline}{section}
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry{tocline}{subsection}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofappendices
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List Of Appendices}

\chapter{Chapter one}
\chapter{Chapter two}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix one}\appcaption{Appendix one}
...(contents of appendix one)...

\chapter{Appendix two}\appcaption{Appendix two}
...(contents of appendix two)...

\end{document}
```

whihc would give you:

[image]

Comment: When I compile your code, the page number still bold.

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya Did you just compile the given MWE? Because, I am pretty sure it was not **bold** for me.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure it was bold for me.  Can you send me again your code? what's the difference from the previous code?

Comment: please see the edited my question above, I give the picture of your code's result.

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya Let me recheck mine